# Uninitialized static variable in memory in Java

Tags: java, memory, static

In the example below, is memory allocated to j?  If so, can the j's address change throughout the program assuming that j will never be initialized?

```
public class c{
    private static String j;
    public c(){}
    ....
}
```

Comment: Java has no concept of an "address".

Comment: are you by some chance talking about reference id?-1.

Comment: I cannot understand what are you asking about... can you make it a bit more clear?

Comment: @Deepanshu Bedi I mean reference

Comment: Java also has no concept of memory allocation.

Comment: Java does have a concept of memory structure through the Unsafe API, MemoryMapped, etc. It would be more beneficial however to realize the author's talking about object references and instead of saying "Java has no concept of an 'address' ", you direct him to a resource on how Java handles references.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM will lazy load a class.  Upon first reference to the class, the class will be allocated and yes memory will be laid out for all of the static fields.  In this case, j will hold 'null'.  Where the class and its fields will be allocated will depend on the JVM, and most specifically the Garbage Collector that was selected.

The Java language does not give direct access to the underlying memory address as other languages such as C do.  And yes, the underlying memory address may change as/when/if the Garbage Collector decides to relocate the class; Some GCs will not relocate classes, the old ones could not even reclaim them.  It is important to note that any move by the GC is not visible to the Java program.  That is, so long as you avoid using sun.misc.Unsafe, sun.misc.Unsafe is a back door to the JVM that was added in Java 5.

For more details on Unsafe, this [blog](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/) has a nice overview.

Comment: just my 2 cent. As j is a String, which is an immutable object, every time the value of j changes jvm will create a new object, so reference of j will change too.

Comment: @holap - two different things.  There is the storage of "j" the pointer to an object, and there is the storage of the object itself (if any).  Since the object is immutable a new one must be created, but the pointer itself would have only its value changed to point to the new object, not its storage location.  Changing the location where the pointer itself is stored would tend to occur only for the convenience of the JVM and its memory manager.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is *Java*. Therefore no talking of address accessing and address change.

The compiler does all this on the behalf of the user for the optimisation and efficiency of the program.

Next, as the variable j has been declared static, you can't decide about the address, but its value will be permanent on declaration even after the end of its block, unless changed. (It means it doesn't lose the value even after the blocks accessing it and declaring it change.)

It'll only lose its value after termination of the program!

Answer (score 1):

> In the example below is memory allocated to j?

Memory is allocated by the JVM to the frame that includes the `j` static variable.  And it *will* be default initialized to `null`.  However, `null` does not refer to any heap node.

> If so, can the j's address change throughout the program assuming that j will never be initialized?

It is not specified, but based on my understanding of how JVMs are typically implemented, yes the address of `j` could change.

However, unless a program tries to access `j` from native code (or equivalent), it won't be aware of the address, or possible changes to it.

Comment: frame, as in the method call stack, or somewhere else?

Comment: Not a stack frame / local frame.  A frame associated with the class.  (Actually, the JVM spec doesn't talk about how / where static variables are represented.  It just says that they are accessed / set using the getStatic / putStatic bytecodes ...

Comment: When static variable (an object) not explicitily initialized, (default to null), does it take any memory?

Comment: @EricWang - yes.  It needs the same amount of memory as would be needed to hold a reference to an object that has been assigned to the variable.

Comment: @EricWang - that is ... 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on the size of a reference on the JVM; i.e. it is platform specific,

Answer (score 0):

You can say it will just point to `null` reference. Memory in Java is allocated using dynamic memory operator i.e. `new` operator (some class like String have special privileges that it can be initialized using `=` operator).

Answer (score -1):

Java is not *C* ... every piece of data (even static variables) gets implicitly initialized (often to `null` or 0), and the compiler won't accept uninitiliazed local variables. Found [this explanation](http://blog.ajduke.in/2012/03/25/variable-initialization-and-default-values/)

Comment: Is this also true of local variables in methods?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't

Comment: Yes @BasileStarynkevitch,these are not initialised to 0 or null by default.Infact,it happens in none of the language for the local variables!